# check if text box is empty then run code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have the following jquery and want to check if the text box is empty before the code is run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#FNameTB").val().length < 0) {
            $("input#FNameTB").labelify({ labelledClass: "greylabel" });
        }       
</script>
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Length will never be less than 0.

```
if ( $("#FNameTB").val().length === 0 )
```

You can even add in a trim() to be thorough

```
if ( $("#FNameTB").val().trim().length === 0 )
```

Comment: Indeed. Less than 0 isn't possible here which is what your condition is testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ($("#FNameTB").val() == '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
if ($('#FNameTB').val() === '') { 
  // It's empty
}
```