# How to check if textbox is empty in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one jquery dialog in my app.

Here Is how It is made

```
    var routePopup = "Route Name : <input type='text' id='routeName' name='routeName'/>";


    document.getElementById('popUp').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('popUp').innerHTML = routePopup;

    $("#popUp").dialog({
        title: "Route Name",
        resizable: false,
        width: auto,
        height: auto,
        buttons: {
            "Create Route": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

now I want to check if textbox is empty or not. If it is empty then it should not allow to close the popup.

Also It should give message on top that the value can not be empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [**Check if textbox has empty value**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565193/check-if-textbox-has-empty-value) or [**check if text box is empty then run code**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350676/check-if-text-box-is-empty-then-run-code) In addition you are asking to solve 3 issues. You should add some of [**the code you have tried**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to address the 3 issues when asking for assistance in finding a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you writing `document.getElementById('popUp').innerHTML = "";` if you could do `$('#popUp').html('');` - that's why you use jQuery :)

```
$("#popUp").dialog({
        title: "Route Name",
        resizable: false,
        width: auto,
        height: auto,
        buttons: {
            "Create Route": function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    alert('May not be empty!');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I also want to give message on top to user if textbox is empty.

Comment: see updated answer. it uses alert() but you can do anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $('#textbox').val();

if (val) {
    //Do whatever...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the input value before checking length:

```
if ( $("#txt").val().trim().length == 0 )
{
    // do something
}
```